# How can i check the runner terminal's sizes in python?

Tags: python

I have a program, and for this I need to know, how many characters can I write to a single line, without count them manually.

Something like this:

```py
window = current_terminal()

width = window.width()

print(width)
```

And the result will:

```
50
```

And i have no idea, how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.get_terminal_size()` method from `os` module. Here is how to use:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.get_terminal_size())
os.terminal_size(columns=80, lines=24)
>>> print(os.get_terminal_size()[0])
80
>>> print(os.get_terminal_size()[1])
24
```

And here is a sample program:

```py
import os

window = os.get_terminal_size()

width = window[0]
height = window[1]

print(width, height)
```

*[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.get_terminal_size)*

*This answer is based on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-get_terminal_size-method/)*